# Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular7

i installed a package via npm in angular(last version) that uses some libs like "fs,stream,.."

when i run `ng serve` it shows many errors like:

```
Can't resolve 'crypto' in '\node_modules\..'
Can't resolve 'fs' in '\node_modules\..'
Can't resolve 'stream' in '\node_modules\..'
```

to resolve the errors i added this code to pckage.json:

```
"browser": {
"fs": false,
"path": false,
"os": false,
"crypto" : false,
"stream" : false,
"http" : false,
"tls" : false,
"zlib" : false,
"https" : false,
"net" : false
}
```

after that i see these two errors:

```
global is not defined
process is not defined
```

to resolve these two i add this part of code to my `polyfills.ts`:

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {
 env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

and errors gone away but now i have this error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.inherits (inherits_browser.js:5)
at Object../node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js (ed-compat.js:25)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js (private-key.js:17)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js (fingerprint.js:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js (key.js:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object../node_modules/sshpk/lib/index.js (index.js:3)
```

i have no idea What should i do!

thanks for any help!

for more info:

the package tested in react and worked fine

package url :https://www.npmjs.com/package/podchat

and the angular componet

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chat from 'podchat';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-c2',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  flag: boolean;
  params = {
    socketAddress: "wss://chat-sandbox.pod.land/ws", // {**REQUIRED**} Socket Address
    ssoHost: "https://accounts.pod.land", // {**REQUIRED**} Socket Address
    platformHost: "https://sandbox.pod.land:8043/srv/basic-platform", // {**REQUIRED**} Platform Core Address
    fileServer: "https://sandbox.pod.land:8443", // {**REQUIRED**} File Server Address
    serverName: "chat-server", // {**REQUIRED**} Server to to register on
    grantDeviceIdFromSSO: false,
    enableCache: true, // Enable Client side caching
    token: "80fdb34b3086438e91061d0902f33c7b", // {**REQUIRED**} SSO Token
    wsConnectionWaitTime: 500, // Time out to wait for socket to get ready after open
    connectionRetryInterval: 5000, // Time interval to retry registering device or registering server
    connectionCheckTimeout: 10000, // Socket connection live time on server
    messageTtl: 86400000, // Message time to live
    reconnectOnClose: true, // auto connect to socket after socket close
    asyncLogging: {
        onFunction: true, // log main actions on console
        onMessageReceive: true, // log received messages on console
        onMessageSend: true, // log sent messaged on console
        actualTiming: true // log actual functions running time
    }
};
  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const chat = new Chat(this.params);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had same problem because lazy loaded module was disk cached because we turned off hashing; after turning on hashing it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library depends of the `fs` package, which is a node.js package to create/read/modify files in your file system. Since you cannot do that in a browser, you will never need those packages. You can remove them.

According to the github page, there is a client part of [podchat](https://github.com/masoudmanson/pod-chat/blob/master/src/chat-browser.js), you should include that instead:

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chat from 'podchat/src/chat-browser';
```

I'm not sure about the correct syntax to import, but I hope you get the idea.